# registration function not working always showing {"error":true,"message":"Required fields are missing"}

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to make a registration form, could anyone please check and tell me what's wrong here?

I am testing it using Postman and it's always showing me the following error:

```
{"error":true,"message":"Required fields are missing"}
```

My DbOperations.php

```
            //For Employee Registration

        public function emplReg($name, $surname, $username, $user_pass, $address, $pin, $mail, $phone){
            $password = md5($user_pass);
            $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO `emp_data` (`name`, `surname`, `username`, `password`, `address`, `pin`, `mail`, `phone`) VALUES ('?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?');");
            $stmt->bind_Param("ssssssss",$name,$surname,$username,$user_pass,$address,$pin,$mail,$phone);
            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                return 1;
            }else{
                return 2;
            }
        }
```

and my emplReg.php

```
 <?php
require_once '../include/DbOperations.php';

$response = array();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    if(
        isset($_POST['reg_name']) and isset($_POST['reg_surname']) and isset($_POST['reg_username']) and isset($_POST['reg_password']) and isset($_POST['reg_address']) and isset($_POST['reg_pin']) and isset($_POST['reg_mail']) and isset($_POST['reg_phone'])
        ){
        //operate the data further

        $db = new DbOperations();

        $result = $db->emplReg( $_POST['reg_name'],
                                    $_POST['reg_surname'],
                                    $_POST['reg_username'],
                                    $_POST['reg_password'],
                                    $_POST['reg_address'],
                                    $_POST['reg_pin'],
                                    $_POST['reg_mail'],
                                    $_POST['reg_phone']
                                );
        if($result == 1){
            $response['error'] = false;
            $response['message'] = "User register successfully";
        }elseif($result == 2){
            $response['error'] = true;
            $response['message'] = "Something wrong, try again";
        }

    }else{
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['message'] = "Required fields are missing";
    }
}else{
    $response['error'] = true;
    $response['message'] = "Invalid Request";
}

echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

[https://www.dropbox.com/s/m0ngx8hqy6vr3t8/Untitled.png?dl=0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/to2kF.png)

Comment: Are you send all required fields via Postman?

Comment: That error message occurs only in one place - in the else to the second if-condition. So the logical conclusion is that _not_ all those $_POST values it checks for are set.

Comment: @PavloZhukov yes...

Comment: @CBroe check the updated image...

Comment: You don’t want to use `form` in postman, but `x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: remove the quotes for all these placeholders `'?'` you should have gotten an error about that. Do that and try again.

Comment: also make sure all POST arrays have value; use error reporting and error handling on the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found three things that you are doing wrong here...

1. in postman you use `x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `form-data`.
2. in bind_Param change `$user_pass` to `$password`.
3. and remove the quotes form all the placeholders `'?'` `?`.